# How to define a function for language terms in php

Tags: php, string, function, variables

I have a function for language (like the system that Wordpress and other CMSes have) to retun a term in defined language as

```
function lang($term) {
include "language/cn.php"; 
if(!empty($tans[$term])) {$translatedterm=$tans[$term];} 
else { $translated = $term;}
return $translated;
}
```

The problem is that I want to offer the option of choosing language on menu, as people can change the language. To this aim, I need to update the value of "include 'language/cn.php'" for every language. It should be `include "language/$language.php";` but `$language` is a string coming from menu selection and is outside the function. Do you have any idea how to change the language file inside the function depending on the language selected?

Comment: there is no 'menu selection' PHP statement. can you please be certain of this variable source?

Comment: I meant a value selected from website menu (not php)

Comment: still it makes no sense. there are no "website menu" PHP statement either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the hint given by Alex Howansky, the ultimate solution is to use a php variable like $_SEESION, $_GET, $_POST, etc. These variable can  be used within a function. However, as a function has its own scope, a static string from outside a function cannot be read inside the function.

Answer (score 1):

In the code that processes the language selection form, you can store the chosen language in the session:

```
$allowed_languages = array('en', ...);
if (array_key_exists($_POST['language'], $allowed_languages)) {
    $_SESSION['language'] = $_POST['language'];
}
```

Then, in this function, pull the language from the session if it's available:

```
function lang($term) {
    $language = isset($_SESSION['language']) ? $_SESSION['language'] : 'en';
    require_once 'language/' . $langauge . '.php';
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This is an excellent point! $_SESSION can be used within the scope of a function. This is should a subtle solution.

Comment: Using _SESSION also solves the problem of persisting the user-selected value of $language from page to page.

Comment: ...and makes it unable to index other languages for the google. how clever.

Comment: I added a clarifying answer to the question based on your idea. Thanks again! I was struggling with this problem for days and discussed it in several forums. Such a subtle approach :)

Answer (score 0):

You're doing this:

```
include 'language/$language.php';
```

This won't work because PHP only interprets variables inside a string when the string is double-quoted. As you've got it there, it will simply take the string as you've specified it, without converting the variable name.

You can either take the variable outside the string like so:

```
include 'language/' . $language.php;
```

or use double-quotes for your string, like so:

```
include "language/{$language}.php";
```

(the curly braces around the variable name are optional in this context, but recommended)

Both of these will result in `$language` being converted to the required value before the file is included.

Hope that helps.

Comment: It was a typo in writing the code. The problem is that php does not bring a string within a function.

Comment: ah right. Well in that case, either pass it in, or use a global (see [`$GLOBALS`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) in the PHP manual)

Answer (score -1):

are you going to include translations file for the EVERY term?

load your translations file **once** and **safe**:

```
function lang($term) {
  static $trans;
  if (!$trans) {
    global $language; // seems the problem as silly as this
    $langfile = "language/".basename($language).".php";
    if (!is_readable($langfile)) {
      $langfile = "language/default.php";
    }
    include $langfile;
  }

  return (empty($trans[$term]))?$term:$trans[$term];
}
```

Comment: Encouraging the use of `global` variables deserves a downvote imo

Comment: ahahaha, another funny orthodox with his superstitions :)